# Ubuntu 12.04 installation time problem

Tags: system-installation

I have had a problem while installing Ubuntu 12.04.

I set the installation size as 10GB and its taking more than 4hrs, then my Broadband goes down.

My system RAM is 2GB and its 32-bit. Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect from Internet. In the top right network icon, Right Click and untick "Enable Networking". This will turn off all network devices

Make sure you make the partitions manually, with an ext4 partition with 10gb root
and 1gb swap space.

I would suggest you unplug your ethernet while installing. Also untick the "Download updates during installation" option. Install Ubuntu normally (it hardly takes 15-25min), and after it's installed, you can use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to update all packages.